# Displaying enumeration values from functions

Tags: c++, function, struct, enums

The idea is to display all the data from the collected from the user in a tabular format according to the structures and enumerations defined. I've gotten some warnings about the use of the switch statement but the most inhibiting thing seems to be the use of the "s.width" when attempting to display the values. When I attempt to compile it advises that it's expecting a semicolon before s in s.width and it continues to move the semicolon to the next value. Is there something incorrect about the way I am referencing the values from my enumerations?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//TODO 1: ShapeKind Enumeration goes here
enum class ShapeKind{
      CIRCLE,SQUARE,RECTANGLE
};

//TODO 2: Shape Structure goes here
struct Shape{
     ShapeKind kind;
     double length, width;
};

// Function prototypes and definitions
double area(Shape s);
//TODO 3: area() definition goes here
double area(Shape s){
  double a;
    switch(s.kind){
      case ShapeKind::CIRCLE:
        return a= (s.length * s.width * 3.14) /4 ;
      case ShapeKind::SQUARE:
        return a = s.length *s.length;
      case ShapeKind::RECTANGLE:
        return a = s.length * s.width;

    }

}

double perimeter(Shape s);
//TODO 4: perimeter() definition goes here

double perimeter(Shape s){
  double p;
  switch(s.kind){
      case ShapeKind::CIRCLE:
        return p= s.length * 3.14;

      case ShapeKind::SQUARE:
        return p = s.length *4;

      case ShapeKind::RECTANGLE:
        return p = 2 *(s.length + s.width);

    }


}

string nameOf(Shape s);
//TODO 5: nameOf() definition goes here
string nameof(Shape s){
  switch(s.kind){
      case ShapeKind::CIRCLE:
        return "Circle";
      case ShapeKind::SQUARE:
        return "Square";
      case ShapeKind::RECTANGLE:
        return "Rectangle";

    }
}

void promptAndReadInputFor(Shape& shape);
//TODO 6: promptAndReadInputFor() definition goes here
void promptAndReadInputFor(Shape& s){
    switch(s.kind){

      case ShapeKind::CIRCLE:
        cout <<"Enter the diameter or a circle: "<< endl;
        cin >> s.length;
        s.width =s.length;

      case ShapeKind::SQUARE:
        cout << "Enter the length of one side: "<< endl;
        cin >>s.length;
        s.width=s.length;

      case ShapeKind::RECTANGLE:
        cout << "Enter the length and width: "<< endl;
        cin >>s.length>>s.width;

          if (s.length == s.width)
            {
              s.kind = ShapeKind::SQUARE; 
            }


    }


};

// The main function
int main() {
  // Shape objects
  Shape circle = { ShapeKind::CIRCLE, 0, 0 };
  //TODO 7: define two more shape objects: a square and and a rectangle
  Shape square= {ShapeKind::SQUARE, 0, 0};
  Shape rectangle ={ShapeKind::RECTANGLE, 0, 0}; 

  //TODO 8: Call the promptAndReadInputFor() function on each of the above three shapes
    promptAndReadInputFor(circle);
    promptAndReadInputFor(square);
    promptAndReadInputFor(rectangle);

  //TODO 9: Print a out a report of these shapes in a table-like format

cout << setw(4) << "Shape" << setw(4) << "Width" << setw(4) << "Height" << setw(4) << "Perimeter"<< setw(4) << "Area"<<endl;    
cout << setw(4) << nameOf(circle) << setw(4) s.width  << setw(4) s.length << setw(4) perimeter(circle)<< setw(4) << area(circle)<< endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `<<`

```
cout << setw(4) << nameOf(circle) << setw(4)  s.width  << setw(4) s.length
    //                                      ^HERE there should probably be '<<' 
    << setw(4) perimeter(circle)<< setw(4) << area(circle)<< endl;
```

Comment: thanks I didn't even notice that between all the late nights. It's now advising me that my identifier s is undefined so i'll try circle.width and see if it works out for me. Thank you for pointing out this blunder. I've been a bit burnt out.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, your function declaration of `nameOf` and definition `nameof` are different;

should be same

```
    string nameOf(Shape s); 

    string nameof(Shape s) {} // not the same in your code
```

and one more change needed,

you have not declared any local `s` variable inside main, you are declared as `circle` your `Shape` object.

Comment: Thank you. I literally just made these corrections after the previous comment started to point me in the direction. I also corrected my switch statements to have a return 0 statement in each function and my code appears to be error free but now when I try to run it, i'm being advised that no such file or directory exists even though it's been compiling so I'm going to see if I can figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed all the bugs. Wanna thank you for your help and also pass on some info for anyone that might need help with something similar. My promptAndReadInputFor function was missing a return statement for each case which caused the function to never end. Both answers I received were correct as the references made for "s.width, s.etc" weren't applicable within the scope of the main function so changing them to "circle, square, etc" which were the objects created to be used solved the issue. I appreciate the assistance you guys provided. Felt great to finally solve this problem.